# Time for creation of database on site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

When and where would you create database to develop web site using ASP.NET MVC 2 and Entity Framework 4 (CreateDatabase method). I think about first run of web site and redirect on welcome page, when controller creates database from model. But I doubt about details:
1. Where? In HttpModule, but request of any image or css will check that database exist. In custom RouteHandler, but then anybody need to know that need to use this handler when to add route. In BaseController, but then code will look like SomeController(..., IDatabase database) : base(database).
2. When? Better create database on first run by any url or may be on deployment of site (additional tool which create ObjectContext and invoke CreateDatabase)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it on first run. What if the account accessing the DB doesn't have the right to create DBs?

We do it during the install.